# Adding deliberate imperfection to RNG output - toolkits?

Tags: statistics, random-number-generation

Are there any existing software toolkits, libraries, frameworks or whatever for studying the quality of pseudorandom number generators that allow one to add a known amount of imperfection - e.g deliberate higher-order correlations - then obtain statistics of various RNGs whose outputs are so modified?

Comment: I suppose you're talking about something more than quasi random number generators?

Comment: I'm wanting to create imperfect random numbers 1) to test the methods by which we test RNGs and 2) to see just what effects imperfect RNGs have on physics simulations, Monte Carlo calculations etc.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at [dieharder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php)?

> Dieharder is a random number generator (rng) testing suite. It is intended to test generators, not files of possibly random numbers as the latter is a fallacious view of what it means to be random. Is the number 7 random? If it is generated by a random process, it might be. If it is made up to serve the purpose of some argument (like this one) it is not. Perfect random number generators produce "unlikely" sequences of random numbers -- at exactly the right average rate. Testing a rng is therefore quite subtle.

Comment: I heard of Dieharder (and Diehard) years ago but wasn't aware of any capability to add imperfection to a good stream of randomness.